# ionic 2 window object doesn't transpile, issue with WebSql window.openDatabase(..)

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am having trouble to use the `window` object in Ionic2.

This question follows the same idea as described in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301003/ionic2-check-if-running-as-ionic-serve-to-use-a-conditionnal-in-the-program).

I found a quite useful input about `window` object [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767595/accessing-window-object-in-ionic-2-angular-2-beta-10). Nevertheless I do have a problem.

**Based on the conditional of the platform I want to use cordova-plugin-sqlite if it runs on a real device, and if it runs on a browser (Chrome), I want to use WebSql.**

I use a service to get the DB connection, in the class regarding that service I've created a function to set the DB value of my service based on conditionnal of the platform kind (and this function is called in [my project]\src\app.components.ts):

```
getDummyDbForBrowerDev(platform){
    console.log('SqlSettingsService() getDummyDbForBrowerDev starts');
    if(platform.is('core')){
        console.info(window);
        this.db = window.openDatabase("ionic2BrowserDev","1.0","",5*1024*1024);
    }   
}
```

As it is the function does not transpile, I get an error when "Ionic serve" is running saying that:

> Property "openDatabase" does not exist on type "window"

What I really don't get is that: If I comment: `//      this.db = window.openDatabase("ionic2BrowserDev","1.0","",5*1024*1024);`

Then it transpiles fine. And in my brower the `console.info(window)` displays a list of all properties underneath the `window` object, and I can see that it includes `openDatabase`.

So I am really confuse why it cannot transpile.

Has anyone a clue of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is kind of an unpopular move to post a question and shortly after to bring the answer.

But I did solve my problem. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767595/accessing-window-object-in-ionic-2-angular-2-beta-10) had the solution. To implement the `windowService` as explained in the given solution totally made it work. It transpiled and openDatabase() was a success.

Thanks to @toskv and @sebaferreras.